# Password reset - security access

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I created a website application using React & Symfony/Apiplateform.
I have a problem when I try to implement the password reset by user

I made something, but to work perfectly, I need to give Anonymously right access to mywebsite/api/users?email=contact@mail.com, and in the same time prohibiting access to "users" entities for those not connected.

To clarify, I need something in my security.yaml like :

```
-{path:^/api/users?email=contact@mail.com, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET]}  => what to put here ? a pattern ?
-{path:^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, methods: [GET, PUT, DELETE] }
```

Or if there's a simpler solution, I'm interested.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to add one route that would provide the access you need.

```
# security.yaml

- {path:^/api/users/email-access, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
- {path:^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
```

and add action in your controller

```
// UserController.php
// class UserController

#[Route('/api/users/email-access', name="api_users_email_access")]
public function emailAccess() {
     $email = $request->query->get('email');
    // do u access for email 
}
```

---

Or you can do this, but it will not be very nice in the controller

```
# security.yaml

- {path:^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

and

```
// UserController.php
// class UserController

#[Route('/api/users', name="api_users")]
public function index(Request $request) {
  if ($request->isMethod('GET') && $request->query->has('email')) {
     $email = $request->query->get('email');
    // do u access for email 
  } elseif (\in_array($request->getMethod(), ['GET, PUT, DELETE'], true)) {
    // check this user auth
  }

  throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull !
I added in react side :
`code`function resetUserPassword(email){
  return Axios.post("/change-password/"+email).then(
    response => response.data);
}
`code`
And in my controller the "change-password" route.
I didn't even have to add something in my security.yaml